# Correct way to conduct private key operation from PKCS11 for mTLS connection in Go

Tags: go, openssl, mqtt, pkcs#11, softhsm

I have successfully imported the private key into the PKCS11 token. The token object looks like this:

```
Private Key Object; RSA 
  label:      #####
  ID:         #####
  Usage:      decrypt, sign, unwrap
  Access:     sensitive
Public Key Object; RSA 2048 bits
  label:      #####
  ID:         #####
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap
  Access:     none
```

I learned that CKA_VALUE usually could not be extracted. And I would like to know what is the correct procedure to create mTLS connection by using pkcs#11 private key and certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> I learned that `CKA_VALUE` usually could not be extracted

Just in case, check out [ThalesIgnite/crypto11 `exportDSAPublicKey()`](https://github.com/ThalesIgnite/crypto11/blob/a81014c7c41025fb5533c0c6b1b14bec016be695/dsa.go#L40-L66) which does export `pkcs11.Attribute`, including `pcs11.CKA_VALUE`, using the public key.
(`CKA_VALUE` is one of the [`ECDSA` private key objects](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v210/group__SEC__10__9__3__ECDSA__PRIVATE__KEY__OBJECTS.html))

For mTLS, check if [`miekg/pkcs11`](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11) can help (not tested).
It can at least help creating a tlsConfig based on private key and certificate.

```golang
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{
        {
            PrivateKey: privateKey,
            Cert:       cert,
        },
    },
}
```

Those should be extracted from your pkcs11 file:

```golang
privateKey, err := p.FindObject(session, []*pkcs11.Attribute{
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_LABEL, "private_key_label"),
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

cert, err := p.FindObject(session, []*pkcs11.Attribute{
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
    pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_LABEL, "certificate_label"),
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

That does not seem to require `CKA_VALUE`